# Why $(a+b)^n$ is called Newton's binomial?

Tags: combinatorics

When we expand $(a + b)^2$, I get three items $a^2$, $2ab$ and $b^2$. 
In general expand $(a + b)^n$, we get $n+1$ items. 
Why $(a+b)^n$ is called Newton's binomial?

Comment: Is it called just "Newton's binomial", or is it called "Newton's binomial theorem" or "Newton's binomial expansion" or something like that? There's a difference, as you can see.

Comment: $(a+b)$ is two terms, it is binomial before you multiply it out.

Comment: Note. It's called Khayyam-Newton binomial expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard it called that, but I assume it's because Newton is credited with the proof of the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem).